# Numpy: How can I index the rows of one matrix using indices found in the rows of another?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, vectorization

I have two (2000, 10) matrices: `weight_values` contains a set of values and `weight_indexes` contains a set of integers to be used as indexes to a new matrix.

I would like to use `weight_indexes` to select entries from a new (2000, 2000) zero matrix and then set those columns to be the values found in the value matrix.

For example, doing this gets me what I want:

```
weights = np.zeros((2000, 2000))
    
for i in range(weight_indexes.shape[0]):
    weights[i, weight_indexes[i]] = weight_values[i]
```

However when I try doing this using array indexing it doesn't work. Indexing `weights` using `weight_indexes` like this:

```
weights[:, weight_indexes[:]]
```

...rather than selecting the appropriate columns from `weights` , this creates a new (2000, 2000, 10) sized matrix.

Is there some vectorised way I can do this without using loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python fancy indices broadcast together. If you want to set 10 elements in each row of `weights`, make `i` broadcast to the same shape as `weight_indexes`:

```
weights[np.arange(len(weight_indexes))[:, None], weight_indexes] = weight_values
```